# NPM install bunch of packages not from package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm

Using Visual Studio code as IDE but lately when I run the command - npm install from the app folder of the solution it installs around 374 items under "node_modules" instead of just installing the packages from the package.json file.

Can someone please provide some pointers for this behavior?

My versions:
node -v
v6.9.1
npm -v
3.10.8

Comment: those things depend on other things

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `node_modules` folder and find one of the folders matching the libraries from your `package.json` file. Inside you will find another `package.json` which describes this library. It is most likely it will also have at least a couple of entries in `dependencies` section.

When you run `npm install` npm builds so-called 'dependency tree'. It starts with your top-level `package.json` and checks what dependencies needs to be installed, then (using its registry) it checks what are the dependencies of these dependencies and then their dependencies and so on...

It is prudent (but often neglected) to check what are the dependencies of the libraries you decide to use. Some of them might have licenses incompatible with yours. Some of them might need a ton of code to perform a simple thing. Many will use deprecated versions, which will spam your `npm install` log with warnings and might actually cause some conflicts with your other dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked couple of libraries from my package.json as suggested by  you but none of them have any of the dependencies which npm installed. This started happening recently only on my machine. I also notice there is a ".bin" folder under node_modules. I am not sure about it?

Comment: If you add a list of those deps to your question, we might have a look at it together