# Rails 6 - what's the folder node_modules inside my app?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, node-modules, yarnpkg

I try to create new Rails 6 app. When I do this, Rails create new folder node_modules. inside it, there are many other folders (packages) that I didn't install.

**1. What's the folder node_modules inside my app?**
**2. Why do I need it? And why do I need all default packages inside it?**
**3. Is it possible not to copy all these packages?**
**4. There are only 5 dependencies in the file myapp/package.json, and more than 700 are installed in the folder myapp/node_modules/. Why?**

---

My path to install Rails:

download and install Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install rbenv ruby-build
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
rbenv install 3.0.0
rbenv global 3.0.0
gem install rails -v 6.1.0
rbenv rehash
brew install yarn
```

Create new Rails app:

```
rails new myapp  
      create  
      ...
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  webpacker:install
      create  config/webpacker.yml
Copying webpack core config
      create  config/webpack
      create  config/webpack/development.js
      create  config/webpack/environment.js
      create  config/webpack/production.js
      create  config/webpack/test.js
Copying postcss.config.js to app root directory
      create  postcss.config.js
Copying babel.config.js to app root directory
      create  babel.config.js
Copying .browserslistrc to app root directory
      create  .browserslistrc
The JavaScript app source directory already exists
       apply  /Users/nikolaylipovtsev/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/install/binstubs.rb
  Copying binstubs
       exist    bin
      create    bin/webpack
      create    bin/webpack-dev-server
      append  .gitignore
Installing all JavaScript dependencies [5.2.1]
         run  yarn add @rails/webpacker@5.2.1 from "."
yarn add v1.22.10
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > chokidar > fsevents@2.1.3: Please update to v 2.2.x
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 603 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @rails/actioncable@6.1.0
├─ @rails/activestorage@6.1.0
├─ @rails/ujs@6.1.0
├─ @rails/webpacker@5.2.1
└─ turbolinks@5.2.0
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/code-frame@7.12.11
├─ @babel/compat-data@7.12.7
├─ @babel/core@7.12.10
├─ @babel/generator@7.12.11
├─ @babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@7.10.4
├─ @babel/helper-compilation-targets@7.12.5
├─ @babel/helper-define-map@7.10.5
├─ @babel/helper-explode-assignable-expression@7.12.1
├─ @babel/helper-get-function-arity@7.12.10
├─ @babel/helper-hoist-variables@7.10.4
├─ @babel/helper-member-expression-to-functions@7.12.7
├─ @babel/helper-validator-option@7.12.11
├─ @babel/helper-wrap-function@7.12.3
├─ @babel/helpers@7.12.5
├─ @babel/highlight@7.10.4
├─ @babel/parser@7.12.11
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.12.12
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.12.7
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.12.7
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-top-level-await@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoped-functions@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping@7.12.12
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-classes@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-computed-properties@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-dotall-regex@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-duplicate-keys@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-for-of@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-function-name@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-literals@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-modules-amd@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-modules-systemjs@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-modules-umd@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-new-target@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-object-super@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-property-literals@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-reserved-words@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.12.10
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-spread@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-sticky-regex@7.12.7
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-template-literals@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typeof-symbol@7.12.10
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-escapes@7.12.1
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-unicode-regex@7.12.1
├─ @babel/preset-env@7.12.11
├─ @babel/preset-modules@0.1.4
├─ @babel/runtime@7.12.5
├─ @babel/traverse@7.12.12
├─ @npmcli/move-file@1.0.1
├─ @rails/actioncable@6.1.0
├─ @rails/activestorage@6.1.0
├─ @rails/ujs@6.1.0
├─ @rails/webpacker@5.2.1
├─ @types/json-schema@7.0.6
├─ @types/node@14.14.19
├─ @types/parse-json@4.0.0
├─ @types/q@1.5.4
├─ @webassemblyjs/floating-point-hex-parser@1.9.0
├─ @webassemblyjs/helper-code-frame@1.9.0
├─ @webassemblyjs/helper-fsm@1.9.0
├─ @webassemblyjs/helper-wasm-section@1.9.0
├─ @webassemblyjs/wasm-edit@1.9.0
├─ @webassemblyjs/wasm-opt@1.9.0
├─ @xtuc/ieee754@1.2.0
├─ abbrev@1.1.1
├─ acorn@6.4.2
├─ aggregate-error@3.1.0
├─ ajv-errors@1.0.1
├─ ajv-keywords@3.5.2
├─ ajv@6.12.6
├─ amdefine@1.0.1
├─ ansi-styles@3.2.1
├─ anymatch@3.1.1
├─ are-we-there-yet@1.1.5
├─ argparse@1.0.10
├─ arr-flatten@1.1.0
├─ array-find-index@1.0.2
├─ asn1.js@5.4.1
├─ asn1@0.2.4
├─ assert@1.5.0
├─ assign-symbols@1.0.0
├─ async-each@1.0.3
├─ async-foreach@0.1.3
├─ asynckit@0.4.0
├─ atob@2.1.2
├─ autoprefixer@9.8.6
├─ aws-sign2@0.7.0
├─ aws4@1.11.0
├─ babel-loader@8.2.2
├─ babel-plugin-macros@2.8.0
├─ base@0.11.2
├─ base64-js@1.5.1
├─ bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2
├─ binary-extensions@2.1.0
├─ bindings@1.5.0
├─ block-stream@0.0.9
├─ bluebird@3.7.2
├─ boolbase@1.0.0
├─ brace-expansion@1.1.11
├─ braces@2.3.2
├─ browserify-aes@1.2.0
├─ browserify-cipher@1.0.1
├─ browserify-des@1.0.2
├─ browserify-rsa@4.1.0
├─ browserify-sign@4.2.1
├─ browserify-zlib@0.2.0
├─ browserslist@4.16.0
├─ buffer-xor@1.0.3
├─ buffer@4.9.2
├─ builtin-status-codes@3.0.0
├─ cache-base@1.0.1
├─ caller-callsite@2.0.0
├─ caller-path@2.0.0
├─ callsites@2.0.0
├─ camelcase-keys@2.1.0
├─ camelcase@5.3.1
├─ caniuse-lite@1.0.30001173
├─ case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin@2.3.0
├─ caseless@0.12.0
├─ chokidar@3.4.3
├─ chrome-trace-event@1.0.2
├─ class-utils@0.3.6
├─ clean-stack@2.2.0
├─ cliui@5.0.0
├─ clone-deep@4.0.1
├─ coa@2.0.2
├─ code-point-at@1.1.0
├─ collection-visit@1.0.0
├─ color-convert@1.9.3
├─ color-name@1.1.3
├─ color-string@1.5.4
├─ color@3.1.3
├─ combined-stream@1.0.8
├─ compression-webpack-plugin@4.0.1
├─ concat-map@0.0.1
├─ concat-stream@1.6.2
├─ console-browserify@1.2.0
├─ console-control-strings@1.1.0
├─ constants-browserify@1.0.0
├─ convert-source-map@1.7.0
├─ copy-concurrently@1.0.5
├─ copy-descriptor@0.1.1
├─ core-js-compat@3.8.2
├─ core-js@3.8.2
├─ core-util-is@1.0.2
├─ create-ecdh@4.0.4
├─ create-hmac@1.1.7
├─ cross-spawn@3.0.1
├─ crypto-browserify@3.12.0
├─ css-blank-pseudo@0.1.4
├─ css-color-names@0.0.4
├─ css-declaration-sorter@4.0.1
├─ css-has-pseudo@0.10.0
├─ css-loader@3.6.0
├─ css-prefers-color-scheme@3.1.1
├─ css-select-base-adapter@0.1.1
├─ css-select@2.1.0
├─ css-tree@1.0.0-alpha.37
├─ css-what@3.4.2
├─ cssdb@4.4.0
├─ cssnano-preset-default@4.0.7
├─ cssnano-util-raw-cache@4.0.1
├─ cssnano-util-same-parent@4.0.1
├─ cssnano@4.1.10
├─ csso@4.2.0
├─ currently-unhandled@0.4.1
├─ cyclist@1.0.1
├─ dashdash@1.14.1
├─ debug@2.6.9
├─ decamelize@1.2.0
├─ decode-uri-component@0.2.0
├─ delayed-stream@1.0.0
├─ delegates@1.0.0
├─ des.js@1.0.1
├─ detect-file@1.0.0
├─ diffie-hellman@5.0.3
├─ dom-serializer@0.2.2
├─ domain-browser@1.2.0
├─ domelementtype@1.3.1
├─ domutils@1.7.0
├─ dot-prop@5.3.0
├─ duplexify@3.7.1
├─ ecc-jsbn@0.1.2
├─ electron-to-chromium@1.3.633
├─ emoji-regex@7.0.3
├─ end-of-stream@1.4.4
├─ enhanced-resolve@4.3.0
├─ entities@2.1.0
├─ errno@0.1.8
├─ error-ex@1.3.2
├─ escalade@3.1.1
├─ escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
├─ eslint-scope@4.0.3
├─ esprima@4.0.1
├─ esrecurse@4.3.0
├─ estraverse@4.3.0
├─ esutils@2.0.3
├─ events@3.2.0
├─ expand-brackets@2.1.4
├─ expand-tilde@2.0.2
├─ extend@3.0.2
├─ extglob@2.0.4
├─ extsprintf@1.3.0
├─ fast-deep-equal@3.1.3
├─ fast-json-stable-stringify@2.1.0
├─ file-loader@6.2.0
├─ file-uri-to-path@1.0.0
├─ fill-range@4.0.0
├─ findup-sync@3.0.0
├─ flatted@3.1.0
├─ flatten@1.0.3
├─ flush-write-stream@1.1.1
├─ for-in@1.0.2
├─ forever-agent@0.6.1
├─ form-data@2.3.3
├─ from2@2.3.0
├─ fs.realpath@1.0.0
├─ fsevents@2.1.3
├─ fstream@1.0.12
├─ gauge@2.7.4
├─ gaze@1.1.3
├─ gensync@1.0.0-beta.2
├─ get-caller-file@2.0.5
├─ get-intrinsic@1.0.2
├─ get-value@2.0.6
├─ getpass@0.1.7
├─ glob-parent@5.1.1
├─ glob@7.1.6
├─ global-modules@2.0.0
├─ global-prefix@3.0.0
├─ globule@1.3.2
├─ graceful-fs@4.2.4
├─ har-schema@2.0.0
├─ har-validator@5.1.5
├─ has-ansi@2.0.0
├─ has-unicode@2.0.1
├─ has-value@1.0.0
├─ hash.js@1.1.7
├─ hex-color-regex@1.1.0
├─ hmac-drbg@1.0.1
├─ hosted-git-info@2.8.8
├─ hsl-regex@1.0.0
├─ hsla-regex@1.0.0
├─ html-comment-regex@1.1.2
├─ http-signature@1.2.0
├─ https-browserify@1.0.0
├─ ieee754@1.2.1
├─ import-cwd@2.1.0
├─ import-fresh@2.0.0
├─ import-from@2.1.0
├─ import-local@2.0.0
├─ in-publish@2.0.1
├─ indent-string@4.0.0
├─ infer-owner@1.0.4
├─ inflight@1.0.6
├─ ini@1.3.8
├─ interpret@1.4.0
├─ is-absolute-url@2.1.0
├─ is-accessor-descriptor@1.0.0
├─ is-arrayish@0.2.1
├─ is-binary-path@2.1.0
├─ is-callable@1.2.2
├─ is-color-stop@1.1.0
├─ is-core-module@2.2.0
├─ is-data-descriptor@1.0.0
├─ is-date-object@1.0.2
├─ is-descriptor@1.0.2
├─ is-directory@0.3.1
├─ is-extglob@2.1.1
├─ is-finite@1.1.0
├─ is-glob@4.0.1
├─ is-negative-zero@2.0.1
├─ is-obj@2.0.0
├─ is-plain-obj@1.1.0
├─ is-plain-object@2.0.4
├─ is-resolvable@1.1.0
├─ is-svg@3.0.0
├─ is-symbol@1.0.3
├─ is-typedarray@1.0.0
├─ is-utf8@0.2.1
├─ is-windows@1.0.2
├─ is-wsl@1.1.0
├─ isarray@1.0.0
├─ isexe@2.0.0
├─ isstream@0.1.2
├─ jest-worker@26.6.2
├─ js-base64@2.6.4
├─ js-tokens@4.0.0
├─ jsesc@2.5.2
├─ json-parse-better-errors@1.0.2
├─ json-parse-even-better-errors@2.3.1
├─ json-schema-traverse@0.4.1
├─ json-schema@0.2.3
├─ json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
├─ jsprim@1.4.1
├─ last-call-webpack-plugin@3.0.0
├─ lines-and-columns@1.1.6
├─ load-json-file@1.1.0
├─ loader-runner@2.4.0
├─ locate-path@3.0.0
├─ lodash.get@4.4.2
├─ lodash.has@4.5.2
├─ lodash.memoize@4.1.2
├─ lodash.template@4.5.0
├─ lodash.templatesettings@4.2.0
├─ lodash.uniq@4.5.0
├─ loud-rejection@1.6.0
├─ lru-cache@6.0.0
├─ make-dir@3.1.0
├─ map-obj@1.0.1
├─ map-visit@1.0.0
├─ mdn-data@2.0.4
├─ memory-fs@0.4.1
├─ meow@3.7.0
├─ merge-stream@2.0.0
├─ micromatch@3.1.10
├─ miller-rabin@4.0.1
├─ mime-db@1.45.0
├─ mime-types@2.1.28
├─ mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
├─ minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1
├─ minimatch@3.0.4
├─ minipass-collect@1.0.2
├─ minipass-flush@1.0.5
├─ minipass-pipeline@1.2.4
├─ minizlib@2.1.2
├─ mississippi@3.0.0
├─ mixin-deep@1.3.2
├─ mkdirp@0.5.5
├─ move-concurrently@1.0.1
├─ ms@2.0.0
├─ nan@2.14.2
├─ nanomatch@1.2.13
├─ neo-async@2.6.2
├─ nice-try@1.0.5
├─ node-gyp@3.8.0
├─ node-libs-browser@2.2.1
├─ node-releases@1.1.67
├─ node-sass@4.14.1
├─ nopt@3.0.6
├─ normalize-package-data@2.5.0
├─ normalize-range@0.1.2
├─ normalize-url@1.9.1
├─ npmlog@4.1.2
├─ nth-check@1.0.2
├─ num2fraction@1.2.2
├─ number-is-nan@1.0.1
├─ oauth-sign@0.9.0
├─ object-assign@4.1.1
├─ object-copy@0.1.0
├─ object.getownpropertydescriptors@2.1.1
├─ object.values@1.1.2
├─ optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.4
├─ os-browserify@0.3.0
├─ os-homedir@1.0.2
├─ os-tmpdir@1.0.2
├─ osenv@0.1.5
├─ p-limit@2.3.0
├─ p-locate@3.0.0
├─ p-map@4.0.0
├─ p-try@2.2.0
├─ pako@1.0.11
├─ parallel-transform@1.2.0
├─ parent-module@1.0.1
├─ parse-asn1@5.1.6
├─ parse-json@4.0.0
├─ parse-passwd@1.0.0
├─ pascalcase@0.1.1
├─ path-browserify@0.0.1
├─ path-complete-extname@1.0.0
├─ path-dirname@1.0.2
├─ path-exists@3.0.0
├─ path-is-absolute@1.0.1
├─ path-key@2.0.1
├─ path-parse@1.0.6
├─ path-type@4.0.0
├─ performance-now@2.1.0
├─ picomatch@2.2.2
├─ pinkie@2.0.4
├─ pnp-webpack-plugin@1.6.4
├─ posix-character-classes@0.1.1
├─ postcss-attribute-case-insensitive@4.0.2
├─ postcss-calc@7.0.5
├─ postcss-color-functional-notation@2.0.1
├─ postcss-color-gray@5.0.0
├─ postcss-color-hex-alpha@5.0.3
├─ postcss-color-mod-function@3.0.3
├─ postcss-color-rebeccapurple@4.0.1
├─ postcss-colormin@4.0.3
├─ postcss-convert-values@4.0.1
├─ postcss-custom-media@7.0.8
├─ postcss-custom-properties@8.0.11
├─ postcss-custom-selectors@5.1.2
├─ postcss-dir-pseudo-class@5.0.0
├─ postcss-discard-comments@4.0.2
├─ postcss-discard-duplicates@4.0.2
├─ postcss-discard-empty@4.0.1
├─ postcss-discard-overridden@4.0.1
├─ postcss-double-position-gradients@1.0.0
├─ postcss-env-function@2.0.2
├─ postcss-flexbugs-fixes@4.2.1
├─ postcss-focus-visible@4.0.0
├─ postcss-focus-within@3.0.0
├─ postcss-font-variant@4.0.1
├─ postcss-gap-properties@2.0.0
├─ postcss-image-set-function@3.0.1
├─ postcss-import@12.0.1
├─ postcss-initial@3.0.2
├─ postcss-lab-function@2.0.1
├─ postcss-load-config@2.1.2
├─ postcss-loader@3.0.0
├─ postcss-logical@3.0.0
├─ postcss-media-minmax@4.0.0
├─ postcss-merge-longhand@4.0.11
├─ postcss-merge-rules@4.0.3
├─ postcss-minify-font-values@4.0.2
├─ postcss-minify-gradients@4.0.2
├─ postcss-minify-params@4.0.2
├─ postcss-minify-selectors@4.0.2
├─ postcss-modules-extract-imports@2.0.0
├─ postcss-modules-local-by-default@3.0.3
├─ postcss-modules-scope@2.2.0
├─ postcss-modules-values@3.0.0
├─ postcss-nesting@7.0.1
├─ postcss-normalize-charset@4.0.1
├─ postcss-normalize-display-values@4.0.2
├─ postcss-normalize-positions@4.0.2
├─ postcss-normalize-repeat-style@4.0.2
├─ postcss-normalize-string@4.0.2
├─ postcss-normalize-timing-functions@4.0.2
├─ postcss-normalize-unicode@4.0.1
├─ postcss-normalize-url@4.0.1
├─ postcss-normalize-whitespace@4.0.2
├─ postcss-ordered-values@4.1.2
├─ postcss-overflow-shorthand@2.0.0
├─ postcss-page-break@2.0.0
├─ postcss-place@4.0.1
├─ postcss-preset-env@6.7.0
├─ postcss-pseudo-class-any-link@6.0.0
├─ postcss-reduce-initial@4.0.3
├─ postcss-reduce-transforms@4.0.2
├─ postcss-replace-overflow-wrap@3.0.0
├─ postcss-safe-parser@4.0.2
├─ postcss-selector-matches@4.0.0
├─ postcss-selector-not@4.0.1
├─ postcss-svgo@4.0.2
├─ postcss-unique-selectors@4.0.1
├─ prepend-http@1.0.4
├─ process-nextick-args@2.0.1
├─ process@0.11.10
├─ prr@1.0.1
├─ pseudomap@1.0.2
├─ psl@1.8.0
├─ public-encrypt@4.0.3
├─ pump@3.0.0
├─ pumpify@1.5.1
├─ punycode@2.1.1
├─ q@1.5.1
├─ qs@6.5.2
├─ query-string@4.3.4
├─ querystring-es3@0.2.1
├─ querystring@0.2.0
├─ randomfill@1.0.4
├─ read-cache@1.0.0
├─ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
├─ read-pkg@1.1.0
├─ readable-stream@2.3.7
├─ readdirp@3.5.0
├─ redent@1.0.0
├─ regenerate-unicode-properties@8.2.0
├─ regenerator-runtime@0.13.7
├─ regenerator-transform@0.14.5
├─ regexpu-core@4.7.1
├─ regjsgen@0.5.2
├─ regjsparser@0.6.4
├─ remove-trailing-separator@1.1.0
├─ repeat-element@1.1.3
├─ repeating@2.0.1
├─ request@2.88.2
├─ require-directory@2.1.1
├─ require-main-filename@2.0.0
├─ resolve-cwd@2.0.0
├─ resolve-dir@1.0.1
├─ resolve-url@0.2.1
├─ resolve@1.19.0
├─ ret@0.1.15
├─ rgb-regex@1.0.1
├─ rgba-regex@1.0.0
├─ run-queue@1.0.3
├─ sass-graph@2.2.5
├─ sass-loader@8.0.2
├─ sax@1.2.4
├─ scss-tokenizer@0.2.3
├─ set-blocking@2.0.0
├─ set-value@2.0.1
├─ setimmediate@1.0.5
├─ shallow-clone@3.0.1
├─ shebang-command@1.2.0
├─ shebang-regex@1.0.0
├─ simple-swizzle@0.2.2
├─ snapdragon-node@2.1.1
├─ snapdragon-util@3.0.1
├─ sort-keys@1.1.2
├─ source-list-map@2.0.1
├─ source-map-resolve@0.5.3
├─ source-map-support@0.5.19
├─ source-map-url@0.4.0
├─ spark-md5@3.0.1
├─ spdx-correct@3.1.1
├─ spdx-exceptions@2.3.0
├─ split-string@3.1.0
├─ sprintf-js@1.0.3
├─ sshpk@1.16.1
├─ ssri@8.0.0
├─ stable@0.1.8
├─ static-extend@0.1.2
├─ stdout-stream@1.4.1
├─ stream-browserify@2.0.2
├─ stream-each@1.2.3
├─ stream-http@2.8.3
├─ strict-uri-encode@1.1.0
├─ string_decoder@1.3.0
├─ strip-bom@2.0.0
├─ strip-indent@1.0.1
├─ style-loader@1.3.0
├─ stylehacks@4.0.3
├─ svgo@1.3.2
├─ tar@6.0.5
├─ terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
├─ terser@5.5.1
├─ through2@2.0.5
├─ timers-browserify@2.0.12
├─ timsort@0.3.0
├─ to-arraybuffer@1.0.1
├─ to-fast-properties@2.0.0
├─ to-object-path@0.3.0
├─ to-regex-range@2.1.1
├─ tough-cookie@2.5.0
├─ trim-newlines@1.0.0
├─ true-case-path@1.0.3
├─ ts-pnp@1.2.0
├─ tslib@1.14.1
├─ tty-browserify@0.0.0
├─ tunnel-agent@0.6.0
├─ turbolinks@5.2.0
├─ tweetnacl@0.14.5
├─ typedarray@0.0.6
├─ unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript@1.0.4
├─ unicode-match-property-ecmascript@1.0.4
├─ unicode-match-property-value-ecmascript@1.2.0
├─ unicode-property-aliases-ecmascript@1.1.0
├─ union-value@1.0.1
├─ unique-slug@2.0.2
├─ unquote@1.1.1
├─ unset-value@1.0.0
├─ upath@1.2.0
├─ uri-js@4.4.0
├─ urix@0.1.0
├─ url@0.11.0
├─ use@3.1.1
├─ util-deprecate@1.0.2
├─ util.promisify@1.0.1
├─ util@0.11.1
├─ uuid@3.4.0
├─ v8-compile-cache@2.2.0
├─ validate-npm-package-license@3.0.4
├─ vendors@1.0.4
├─ verror@1.10.0
├─ vm-browserify@1.1.2
├─ watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.1
├─ watchpack@1.7.5
├─ webpack-assets-manifest@3.1.1
├─ webpack-cli@3.3.12
├─ webpack-sources@1.4.3
├─ webpack@4.44.2
├─ which-module@2.0.0
├─ which@1.3.1
├─ wide-align@1.1.3
├─ worker-farm@1.7.0
├─ wrap-ansi@5.1.0
├─ xtend@4.0.2
├─ yaml@1.10.0
├─ yargs-parser@13.1.2
└─ yocto-queue@0.1.0
✨  Done in 89.36s.
Installing dev server for live reloading
         run  yarn add --dev webpack-dev-server from "."
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 102 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ webpack-dev-server@3.11.1
info All dependencies
├─ @types/glob@7.1.3
├─ @types/minimatch@3.0.3
├─ accepts@1.3.7
├─ ansi-colors@3.2.4
├─ ansi-html@0.0.7
├─ array-flatten@1.1.1
├─ array-union@1.0.2
├─ array-uniq@1.0.3
├─ async-limiter@1.0.1
├─ async@2.6.3
├─ batch@0.6.1
├─ body-parser@1.19.0
├─ bonjour@3.5.0
├─ buffer-indexof@1.1.1
├─ compressible@2.0.18
├─ compression@1.7.4
├─ connect-history-api-fallback@1.6.0
├─ content-disposition@0.5.3
├─ cookie-signature@1.0.6
├─ cookie@0.4.0
├─ deep-equal@1.1.1
├─ default-gateway@4.2.0
├─ del@4.1.1
├─ destroy@1.0.4
├─ detect-node@2.0.4
├─ dns-equal@1.0.0
├─ dns-packet@1.3.1
├─ dns-txt@2.0.2
├─ ee-first@1.1.1
├─ eventemitter3@4.0.7
├─ eventsource@1.0.7
├─ execa@1.0.0
├─ express@4.17.1
├─ finalhandler@1.1.2
├─ follow-redirects@1.13.1
├─ forwarded@0.1.2
├─ get-stream@4.1.0
├─ globby@6.1.0
├─ handle-thing@2.0.1
├─ hpack.js@2.1.6
├─ html-entities@1.4.0
├─ http-deceiver@1.2.7
├─ http-parser-js@0.5.3
├─ http-proxy-middleware@0.19.1
├─ http-proxy@1.18.1
├─ internal-ip@4.3.0
├─ ip-regex@2.1.0
├─ ip@1.1.5
├─ ipaddr.js@1.9.1
├─ is-absolute-url@3.0.3
├─ is-arguments@1.1.0
├─ is-path-cwd@2.2.0
├─ is-path-in-cwd@2.1.0
├─ is-path-inside@2.1.0
├─ is-stream@1.1.0
├─ json3@3.3.3
├─ killable@1.0.1
├─ loglevel@1.7.1
├─ media-typer@0.3.0
├─ merge-descriptors@1.0.1
├─ methods@1.1.2
├─ mime@2.4.7
├─ multicast-dns-service-types@1.1.0
├─ multicast-dns@6.2.3
├─ negotiator@0.6.2
├─ node-forge@0.10.0
├─ npm-run-path@2.0.2
├─ object-is@1.1.4
├─ obuf@1.1.2
├─ on-headers@1.0.2
├─ opn@5.5.0
├─ original@1.0.2
├─ p-finally@1.0.0
├─ p-retry@3.0.1
├─ path-is-inside@1.0.2
├─ path-to-regexp@0.1.7
├─ portfinder@1.0.28
├─ proxy-addr@2.0.6
├─ querystringify@2.2.0
├─ raw-body@2.4.0
├─ regexp.prototype.flags@1.3.0
├─ retry@0.12.0
├─ select-hose@2.0.0
├─ selfsigned@1.10.8
├─ serve-index@1.9.1
├─ serve-static@1.14.1
├─ sockjs-client@1.5.0
├─ sockjs@0.3.21
├─ spdy-transport@3.0.0
├─ spdy@4.0.2
├─ strip-eof@1.0.0
├─ thunky@1.1.0
├─ type-is@1.6.18
├─ unpipe@1.0.0
├─ url-parse@1.4.7
├─ utils-merge@1.0.1
├─ wbuf@1.7.3
├─ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3
├─ webpack-dev-server@3.11.1
├─ websocket-driver@0.7.4
├─ websocket-extensions@0.1.4
└─ ws@6.2.1
✨  Done in 20.77s.
Webpacker successfully installed
```

Default package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: @MostafaHussein Just the first question. Not at all

Comment: I guess you might be able to find the answer to each question individually. For example, this should answer question number 4: [NPM install bunch of packages not from package.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683576/npm-install-bunch-of-packages-not-from-package-json-file).